# Resizing a custom view with the window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

So I've seen this question asked a couple times, but haven't come across an answer that solves my problem. Right now I basically have MainMenu.xib with a label centered on the top, a large custom view and a button centered on the bottom that switches subviews of the custom view (see picture below). I've set the window and the custom view to autoresize subviews in the interface builder and all the buttons, labels, etc. have constraints relating them to the sides of the view, but when I resize the window, the contents of the subview do not resize. I think the custom view is resizing with the window because when I switch subviews with the button, the subview that loads is resized with the window, they just aren't resizing with the window in real time.

MainMenu.xib:
[image]

Normal subview:
[image]

After window is expanded:
[image]

Subview switched and then switched back:
[image]

**CONSTRAINTS:**

MainMenu.xib:
[image]

BlockViewController.xib:
[image]

Comment: What are "springs and struts"? I'm using autolayout with the align and pin options in interface builder. I'll upload screenshots of the xibs with constraints showing.

Comment: @Monolo That's not a height constraint, it's an alignment to center the view in the window.

Comment: @Monolo This is my code when I add the BlockViewController to the custom view:

`[self.customView addSubview: self.blockSubView.view];
self.blockSubView.view.frame = self.customView.bounds;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out! Really simple, just one line of code in the awakeFromNib method of each ViewController subclass:

```
[self.view setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
```

Comment: Works for me as well! I have just added constraints in builder and added this code for views in awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 1):

From the pictures and the description in the comments it seems that the problem is that the custom view does not get any layout constraints to determine how to resize the subview.

The following piece of code (typed directly in the browser, so beware) should provide the necessary constraints to "glue" the borders of the subview to the custom view.

```
[self.customView addSubview: self.blockSubView.view];
self.blockSubView.view.frame = self.customView.bounds;

NSView *blockSubView = self.blockSubView.view;

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(blockSubView);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[blockSubView]|"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:viewsDictionary];


constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V|[blockSubView]|"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:viewsDictionary]];

[self.customView addConstraints: constraints];
```

There is more about this in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1). Notice the tricks for debugging - very useful to the point of being indispensable.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason this code makes it so I can't resize the window at all though

Comment: @MattCooper That would be because the constraints on the inner view (the one you add) does not allow it to be resized. Have you tried the debugging tips?

Comment: I just figured it all out with 1 line of code haha, thanks for all of your help and the link to the docs/debugging techniques. I'm sure those will really come in handy.